# how to code a single legend for a figure containing three subfigures with packages caption/ subcaption

Tags: pgfplots, legend

I would like to create a single legend for three subfigures containing scatter plots. Legend should be centered below the overall figure. Can anyone help?

Here the skeleton:

```
\begin{figure}[H] %[htbp]
\centering

\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}[%
      scale=0.7,
      xmin = 0, xmax = a,
      xtick={...},
      xlabel={...},
      xmajorgrids,
      ymin = 0, ymax = b,
      ytick={},
      ylabel={...},      
      ymajorgrids,
      axis background/.style={fill=white},
      legend style={legend cell align=left,draw=black,at={(0.5,-0.25)},anchor=north},
      scatter/classes={%
        REF1={color=black,mark size=2.0pt,only marks,mark=o,mark options={solid}}}]      
    \addplot [name path=high,color=black,dashed,line width=0.5pt] table [col sep=comma,x index=0,y index=1]{img/high.txt};
    \addplot [color=black,solid,line width=0.5pt] table [col sep=comma,x index=0,y index=1]{img/mid.txt};
    \addplot [name path=low,color=black,dotted,line width=0.5pt] table [col sep=comma,x index=0,y index=1]{img/low.txt};    
    \addplot [scatter,only marks,%
      scatter src=explicit symbolic]%
    table[col sep=comma,meta=label,x index=0,y index=1] {img/REF1.txt};
    \addplot [fill=gray,opacity=0.20] fill between[of=high and low];
    \legend{high_leg,mid_leg,low_leg,\cite{REF1}}    
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{...\label{fig:fig1a}}
\end{subfigure}%
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}[%
      scale=0.7,
      xmin = 0, xmax = a,
      xtick={...},
      xlabel={...},
      xmajorgrids,
      ymin = 0, ymax = b,
      ytick={},
      ylabel={...},      
      ymajorgrids,
      axis background/.style={fill=white},
      legend style={legend cell align=left,draw=black,at={(0.5,-0.25)},anchor=north},     
      scatter/classes={%
   REF2={color=black,mark size=2.0pt,only marks,mark=Mercedes star,mark options={solid}}}]
    \addplot [name path=high,color=black,dashed,line width=0.5pt] table [col sep=comma,x index=0,y index=1]{img/high.txt};
    \addplot [color=black,solid,line width=0.5pt] table [col sep=comma,x index=0,y index=1]{img/mid.txt};
    \addplot [name path=low,color=black,dotted,line width=0.5pt] table [col sep=comma,x index=0,y index=1]{img/low.txt};    
    \addplot [scatter,only marks,%
      scatter src=explicit symbolic]%
    table[col sep=comma,meta=label,x index=0,y index=1] {img/REF2.txt};
    \addplot [fill=gray,opacity=0.20] fill between[of=high and low];
    \legend{high_leg,mid_leg,low_leg,\cite{REF2}}    
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{...\label{fig:fig1b}}
\end{subfigure}\\
\vspace{0.5cm}
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}[%
      scale=0.7,
      xmin = 0, xmax = a,
      xtick={...},
      xlabel={...},
      xmajorgrids,
      ymin = 0, ymax = b,
      ytick={},
      ylabel={...},      
      ymajorgrids,
      axis background/.style={fill=white},
      legend style={legend cell align=left,draw=black,at={(0.5,-0.25)},anchor=north},
      scatter/classes={%
   REF2_full={color=black,mark size=2.0pt,only marks,mark=o,mark options={solid}}}]
    \addplot [name path=high,color=black,dashed,line width=0.5pt] table [col sep=comma,x index=0,y index=1]{img/high.txt};
    \addplot [color=black,solid,line width=0.5pt] table [col sep=comma,x index=0,y index=1]{img/mid.txt};
    \addplot [name path=low,color=black,dotted,line width=0.5pt] table [col sep=comma,x index=0,y index=1]{img/low.txt};    
    \addplot [scatter,only marks,%
      scatter src=explicit symbolic]%
    table[col sep=comma,meta=label,x index=0,y index=1] {img/REF2_full.txt};
    \addplot [fill=gray,opacity=0.20] fill between[of=high and low];
    \legend{high_leg,mid_leg,low_leg,\cite{REF1}}    
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{...\label{fig:fig1c}}
\end{subfigure}

\caption{...\label{fig:fig1}}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]! Can you show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: sure. Just a second.

Comment: so, I currently have two problems actually... 1) merging the three legends I currently have into a single legend according to the aforementioned requirements; 2) I use hyperlinks in the legend, which seems to lead to scaling issues. More specifically, the axis labels have different sizes when compared to other similar figures in which I don't make use of hyperlinked legend entries. I'm aware of other options, such as groupplots, or inserting a single legend under the same tikzpicture environment, but I wanted to stick to the subfigure environment for the time being, hence my question. Thanks!

Comment: Pgfplots has the facility to put part or all of a legend into the aux file which can be accessed using \ref{label name}  There are several examples in the related questions ro the right.

Comment: Could you please provide a minimum working example. One we can compile, with only the elements which matter.